# Xamarin Android Build - No package specified

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When creating a shared library application in Xamarin for iOS and Android, i can't install a blank project to either an Android device or the simulator. I get the following error:

> Error - no package specified
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets:
>   Warning: Error: no package specified  (test.Droid)

I have tried a variety of fixes but i don't really know what package it is referring to.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably post the entire error message and also the manifest file. Where is test.Droid defined?

Comment: That is the entire error message.

I'm new to this so apologies if i'm missing something very simple, testDroid is one of the two apps, there is also test.iOS which works perfectly.

This did build to the device before, but for some reason stopped but i don't remember changing anything, especially related to the package.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. The worst part is that there is not too much to show just says deploy failed with one error message: no package specified. After spending hours looking thru the build logs. It boiled down to one very simple solution:

- Repair your Xamarin installation.

  - Make sure Visual Studio is closed.
  - Go to Apps & Features.
  - Find Xamarin in the list.
  - Click Modify.
  - Choose the repair option.

That's it.

P.S. By me this trouble started when I moved around the SDK from folder to another. I was consolidating the SDK used by Xamarin with two(!) other ones used by Android Studio.